# Why are there duplicates generated by Apache Nifi CaptureChangeMySQL?

Tags: mysql, apache-nifi, cdc

- Bin log format is ROW.
- Set concurrent tasks to 1.
- Set Execution on to
- 'Primary Node'. Run schedule - 200 millis
- Retrieve all records : false
- Include ddl events : false
- Include Begin/Commit events : false
- Configured CDCMapCache on localhost.

Started the processor and updated a couple of records in the db.
10 flow files generated. Copies of the same update event are generated (I checked the flow files are they have same binlog-position and update query).

Have I configured it right?
Why could this be happening?

[image: 10 events for 2 updates]

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using, or are you using MariaDB?

Comment: Not mariadb. I am using version 5.7.22 of mysql.